# OpenVPN client fine with Network Manager but not from command line

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, openvpn

After installing network-manager-openvpn-gnome, I do manage to connect to some OpenVPN servers fine by importing some .ovpn files. However, I also want to do it directly on the command line with openvpn but I do not manage.

```
openvpn myvpn.ovpn
```

Seems happy, I can see the new interface with `ip`, but the connection does not work, it looks like a DNS issue.

The same myvpn.ovpn file imported in Network Manager works fine.

I tried to add the following at the end of the .ovpn file:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

But it does not help.
Any pointer?
I have tried openvpn3 but it does not support TAP that I need.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Solved.... I just needed to install `openresolv`
So adding the lines mentioned above to the opvn files are necessary.